# OAuth Url Generation Issue when using Azure Custom Domains

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4

Okay, this is going to be a difficult one to explain and I'm hoping someone out there's solved this before as it's pretty damn niche.

Box A is our authentication box (identity server, IS), it is set to be accessible from auth.website.com.
Box B is our production app (dotnet core app), it is set to be accessible from app.website.com.

The issue is that when either app generates URLS for the custom domain, they use the scheme HTTP rather than HTTPS. This was fixed on the auth box by setting two settings for IS that tells it what its base URL is.

The other part of the issue is that when the app generates is redirect URLs for OAuth, it generates them with the HTTP, not the HTTPS. This meaning that the URLs are invalid in the eye of our auth server.

Is there a way to force .NET Core OAuth to generate its URLS with the correct scheme? Or is there a way to make .NET Core's base scheme HTTPS?

Just as a note, when using the default provided URL blank.azurewebsite.com the URLs generated with the correct scheme.

Comment: Do you have app.UseHttpsRedirection();  in your startup.cs configure?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Hi @DaImTo, we did consider it, but it wouldn't solve the issue just adding the redirects. These are already done by both Cloudflare and Azure.

Comment: we use a simple middleware. `app.Use((context, next) => {context.Request.Scheme = "https"; return next(); });` helps with proxies ets.